# How to change color of text to background color of container div?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to add a CSS transition to my `div` where on hover it changes color to whatever the `background-color` of the `div` is. Basically I am trying to achieve some kind of color inversion if that's the right term.

```css
.container .box {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-family: 'Tourney', cursive;

    transition-property: font-size, color, text-shadow;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transition-duration: 800ms;
}

.box:hover {
    color: black; /* What should I use here? */
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border: solid white 2px;
}
.box1 {
    background-color: chocolate;
}

.box2 {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.box3 {
    background-color: powderblue;
}

.box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
    background-color: seagreen;
}

.box6 {
    background-color: gold;
}

.box7 {
    background-color: firebrick;
}

.box8 {
    background-color: violet;
}

.box9 {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box10 {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box6">6</div>
    <div class="box box7">7</div>
    <div class="box box8">8</div>
    <div class="box box9">9</div>
    <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

As I have marked out with my comment, on `.box:hover { color : .. }`, I don't know what to put there. At first I thought a CSS variable would do the job but they aren't dynamic, which means I would need 10 different CSS variables if I had 10 boxes to invert colors. Is there a clever solution here?

Comment: "whatever the background-color of the div is" Which div? You have 10 divs in a container div, for a total of 11. Also none of them have a background-color set... is there more CSS that isn't included here?

Comment: @TylerH Yes I should include that in my question for clarity.

Comment: @Paulie_D that's an interesting suggestion, I am trying it out.

Comment: @Paulie_D Seems like a good answer to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS variables. Define a variable and use that as your background color for each div. Then transition your `color` to the variable on hover.

```css
:root {
  --mycolor: white;
}

.container .box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: 'Tourney', cursive;
  transition-property: font-size, color, text-shadow;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
}

.box:hover {
  color: var(--mycolor);
  /* What should I use here? */
  font-size: 5em;
  text-shadow: 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: solid white 2px;
}

.box {
  background: var(--mycolor);
}

.box1 {
  --mycolor: chocolate;
}

.box2 {
  --mycolor: rebeccapurple;
}

.box3 {
  --mycolor: powderblue;
}

.box4 {
  --mycolor: orange;
}

.box5 {
  --mycolor: seagreen;
}

.box6 {
  --mycolor: gold;
}

.box7 {
  --mycolor: firebrick;
}

.box8 {
  --mycolor: violet;
}

.box9 {
  --mycolor: aquamarine;
}

.box10 {
  --mycolor: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, for a slightly different effect, transition the text to `transparent`

```css
.container .box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: 'Tourney', cursive;
  transition-property: font-size, color, text-shadow;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
}

.box:hover {
  color: transparent;
  /* What should I use here? */
  font-size: 5em;
  text-shadow: 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: solid white 2px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: gold;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.box8 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.box9 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box10 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you than this might be the solution:
Here is the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) for reference.
I used:

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

```css
.container .box {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: 'Tourney', cursive;
  transition-property: font-size, color, text-shadow;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-duration: 800ms;
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-shadow: 8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: solid white 2px;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.box2 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
}

.box3 {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

.box4 {
  background-color: orange;
}

.box5 {
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.box6 {
  background-color: gold;
}

.box7 {
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.box8 {
  background-color: violet;
}

.box9 {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.box10 {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
  <div class="box box6">6</div>
  <div class="box box7">7</div>
  <div class="box box8">8</div>
  <div class="box box9">9</div>
  <div class="box box10">10</div>
</div>
```